# How to clear AWS RDS Aurora local storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I got a warning message about running out of AWS RDS local storage.

> The free storage capacity for DB Instance: {MY INSTANCE NAME} is low
> at 2% of the provisioned storage [Provisioned Storage: 157.36 GB, Free
> Storage: 3.35 GB]. You may want to increase the provisioned storage to
> address this issue.

According to the AWS document, local storage depends on instance type and can be increased by scale up :
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-mysql-local-storage/?nc1=h_ls

But, I would like to clear the local storage instead of scaling up the instance because only one instance of the read cluster has insufficient local storage.

I restarted Aurora instance but the local storage is still almost full.

How can I clear local storage?

It's MySQL version is 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can clear up some log files from database instance level by deleting them , that might help.
Increase max_heap_table_size/tmp_table_size parameters , tables will consume more memory on the instance thus reducing local storage used.